# Unobtrusive Way to Trim Cycle in Clojure Sequence

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a lazy seq to generate the [Collatz sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html) for a given input int.

I love this function because is so cleanly maps to the mathematical definition:

```clj
(defn collatz
  "Returns a lazy seq of the Collatz sequence starting at n and ending at 1 (if
  ever)."
  [n]
  (letfn [(next-term [x]
            (if (even? x)
              (/ x 2)
              (inc (* 3 x))))]
    (iterate next-term n)))
```

The problem is that this produces infinite seqs because of how the Collatz sequence behaves:

```clj
(take 10 (collatz 5))
  => (5 16 8 4 2 1 4 2 1 4)
```

I could easily drop the cycle by adding `(take-while #(not= 1 %) ...)`, but the 1 *is* part of the sequence. All the other ways I've thought to trim the cycle after the one are ugly and obfuscate the mathematical heart of the Collatz sequence.

(I've considered storing the seen values in an atom and using that in a `take-while` predicate, or just storing a flag in an atom to similar effect. But I feel like there is some better, more beautiful, less intrusive way to do what I want here.)

So my question: What are clean ways to detect and trim cycles in infinite seqs? Or, could I generate my lazy seq in a way (perhaps using `for`) that automatically trims when it reaches `1` (inclusive)?

Comment: For anyone who came here searching for "Clojure" and "Collatz": Memoization is also a great solution here, combined with `cons` and `lazy-seq`. And you can reuse the `collatz-iter` function created in Aleph's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below looks like a more or less literal translation of the definition and gives the result you want:

```
(defn collatz-iter [x]
  (cond (= x 1) nil
        (even? x) (/ x 2)
        :else (inc (* 3 x))))

(defn collatz [n]
  (take-while some? (iterate collatz-iter n)))

(collatz 12) ;; => (12 6 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1)
```

Basically, you can use `nil` as the value to stop the sequence, thus keeping the final 1.

Comment: I completely missed the significance that `collatz-iter`/`next-term` are determining the *next* term -- so if it sees `1`, just emit a terminator placeholder (`nil`) as the next term. Yeah, pretty straightfoward. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use another approach, which is recursive lazy-seq generation. That is quite common for this class of tasks, doesn't break the lazy sequence abstraction and avoids intermediate sequences' creation:

```
(defn collatz [n]
  (if (== n 1)
    (list 1)
    (lazy-seq (cons n (collatz (if (even? n)
                                 (/ n 2)
                                 (inc (* 3 n))))))))

user> (collatz 12)
;;=> (12 6 3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1)
```

Comment: Simpler to write `(cons n (when (not= n 1) (lazy-seq (collatz ...))))`